# Why can I only access the guest session in Ubuntu?

Tags: guest-session

My brother installed Ubuntu on my windows 10 toshiba laptop. At first it was great, but now I can only access the guest session, and can't access the full capability of Ubuntu. I work with my laptop and I'm new to this so any kind of advice or help would be genuinely appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is preventing you from accessing your normal account?

Comment: When I power on my laptop and come to the login screen, the guest account is the only option. My account and my brothers have both disappeared entirely.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. It's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Comment: Can you log in on the virtual terminal with either of your user accounts? You can access it with Ctrl+Alt+F1.

Answer (score 0):

**Getting access when you know your username & password**

Login to tty when the login screen pops up (CTL ALT F1)

Login by typing the correct username and password.

Go back to desktop by using (ctl alt f7)

Now go into

```
settings -> users -> add user
```

Add an admin account. Then remove guest login options.

**Troubleshooting**

To list all users you can use:

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd
```

To add a new user you can use:

```
sudo adduser new_username
```

or:

```
sudo useradd new_username
```

If you can't login to any account previous known or listed you must  [Reset your administrative login.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Comment: I tried both logins and it told me neither account exists.

Comment: Updated answer wish could be more help